# Better way to avoid applying repetitive mongoose method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using the below code in order to first filter documents in mongoose based on some filter. Then I am required to count the documents filtered.
Then, as can be seen in the code, since I have to skip some documents to send to the client, I  have to again apply the find() method in order to filter the documents and then apply the skip() and limit() method.

```
const count = await myModel.find(filterObj).countDocuments();
const docs = await myModel
  .find(filterObj)
  .skip((page - 1) * pageSize)
  .limit(pageSize);
```

Is there any better way so that I can avoid applying the find() method twice since this seems to be costly if we have a large no. of documents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

regarding performance of the action taken in the code snippet there's no further room for optimization `find`, `limit` and `skip` is sufficient enough (Make sure you have indexes to further optimize query times)

NodeJS wise you can use `promise.all` to run queries simultaneously

```
 const count = ()=>await myModel.find(filterObj).countDocuments();
 const docs = ()=>await myModel
 .find(filterObj)
 .skip((page - 1) * pageSize)
 .limit(pageSize);
 const [docsResult,CountResult] = await Promise.all([docs(),count()])
```

Comment: There's other pagination methods using two cursors over data which his identifier is incrementing